# Primitive Translations in Diamond Lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

The Diamond Lattice (e.g. [here](http://phycomp.technion.ac.il/%7Enika/diamond_structure.html)) is an fcc-lattice. For an fcc-lattice,
one set of primitive translation vectors could be

$\left\{ \frac{a}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \frac{a}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \frac{a}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}. $

However, this set of vectors must be slightly modified for the Diamond Lattice, and I'm not quite sure how.
Any hints would be appreciated!

One question I am asking myself is: If I translated the crystal by the vector $$\frac{a}{4}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ would it be invariant under this translation (I cannot imagine it right now)?

Comment: Diamond cubic is an fcc lattice with a two atom basis.

Answer (score 1):

The diamond structure is fcc with two atoms in the basis. If you pick the lattice vectors as you chose:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{a}_1=\frac{a}{2}(1,1,0), \\
\mathbf{a}_2=\frac{a}{2}(1,0,1), \\
\mathbf{a}_3=\frac{a}{2}(0,1,1),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
then you can place the atoms at the following positions to obtain the diamond structure:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(0,0,0), \\
\frac{a}{4}(1,1,1). \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The vector $\mathbf{v}=\frac{a}{4}(1,1,1)$ is the vector connecting the two atoms in the basis, but is *not* a translation vector of the lattice. For the latter, you need a linear combination of the lattice vectors.